# New hats notification icon doesn't quite cover the snowflake under it

Tags: bug, top-bar, winter-bash-2014

This is obviously minor, but you can still see the snowflake icon on the top bar peeking through from behind the notification badge for new hats.

[image: New hats!]

You probably can't even notice it in low resolution, but it's just the slightest bit off.

Answer (score 4):

On Chrome/OSX it's about half a pixel too low (retina display).

[image: osx screenshot]

Regardless, I'm not sure this is worth bothering with.

Comment: I'm on OS X too, so I'm not sure what causes it.

Comment: @AstroCB OS shouldn't matter. What probably matters is the browser.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat Yes; that's what I was insinuating to as a response to Kevin. I'm using Safari 8.0.2.